# UISwitch state is not updated while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        UISwitch *clickButton = (UISwitch *)[cell viewWithTag:30];
        clickButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [clickButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonClickAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UILabel *title = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:80];
        UILabel *description = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:81];
        UIView *innerView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:82];
        innerView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor colorWithRed:229/255.0f green:229/255.0f blue:229/255.0f alpha:1.0]  CGColor];
        innerView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
        NSDictionary *displayDict = scenarioListsArray[indexPath.row];
        title.text =[displayDict objectForKey:@"name"];
        description.text = [displayDict objectForKey:@"description"];
        if ([[displayDict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ACTIVE"]) {
            [clickButton setOn:YES animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"SWITCH %ld",clickButton.tag);
        }
        else
        {
            [clickButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
        }
```

**i need to change the state of Switch depends on Array but switch state not change on array.**

Comment: show that action `cellButtonClickAction` code

Comment: -(void)cellButtonClickAction:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",sender.tag);
    NSInteger value = sender.isOn;
    NSString *action;
    if (value==1) {
        action = @"activate";
        [self scenarioStatusChanging:[scenarioListsArray[sender.tag] objectForKey:@"scenarioId"] action:action];
    }
    else
    {
        action = @"deactivate";
        [self scenarioStatusChanging:[scenarioListsArray[sender.tag] objectForKey:@"scenarioId"] action:action];
  
    }   
}